# how to trim the white spaces before and after ":"

Tags: python

I am looking for some inputs on python coding. My input text file is like below

```
key1 <space> <space>: <space> value1
key2:value2
key3:<spaces><space>value3
```

Either : or - will be there for key value separation. I want a uniform output like

```
key1 <1space>:<1space>value1
key2 <1space>:<1space>value2
key3 <1space>:<1space>value3
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'\s*:\s*', '  : ', s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kS5sL9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Or without regexp:

```
key, value = [k.strip() for k in line.split(':')]
```

Work only if you are sure there is exactly one `:` for each line

Comment: yep, yours is better

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex or list comprehension:

```
key, value = line.replace(' ','').split(':')
'{} : {}'.format(key, value)
```

This removed all spaces from the input line, which can be an issue if there are spaces use in the key or value.